# show an query error

Tags: compile-error

I have a test class its shown an this error

> System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'BY' in this line

don't get what exactly wrong with this statement

```
public static List<PO_Line_Item__c> fillPOLineItem(sObject childSobject,String childNameSpace,String fieldSetName, String prefix, Set<String> setPoId){
        return database.query(getPOLineItemQuery(childSobject,childNameSpace,fieldSetName,prefix,setPoId)+'ORDER BY Name Asc');
    }
```

This method call in test class which shown an error like this

Comment: better you post your `getPOLineItemQuery` method code as well. You may need space character before `ORDER`, if you don't have already

Comment: You can just debug your query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a space between Object Name and Order keyword

```
String strQuery = 'Select Id, Name from AccountOrder BY Name DESC'; // Dynamic Query String Generated

// There should be a space between Object Name and Order keyword

String strQuery = 'Select Id, Name from Account Order BY Name DESC'; 

List<Account> accountList = Database.query(strQuery);

System.debug('Account List ###'+accountList );
```

[Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm)

Comment: hi devendra i wrote like this but it not work                                                                     return database.query(getPOLineItemQuery(childSobject,childNameSpace,fieldSetName,prefix,setPoId)+ '' +'ORDER BY Name Asc');

Comment: Give a space before ORDER keyword and check. database.query(getPOLineItemQuery(childSobject,childNameSpac‌​e,fieldSetName,prefi‌​x,setPoId)+ '' +' ORDER BY Name Asc');

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing space between your object name and ORDER. Add a space and you are good to go.